# XCode Linker Error 1 - Global Array Error?

Tags: c++, arrays, macos, linker, global

i written a C++ Projekt in Visual Studio 13 and now i wanted to Compile it on a mac to. 
After i checked up my code, i get a linker error 1 now, with the specification:

ld: 6 dublicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

over that i can see some of my created files, like Listener.o and main.o

I got a look in that and und looks like the global arrays are the problem but i didn't know why because i only declare the array's in the headers, no define in there...

Ok, let's have a look into the code.

Listener.h

```
#include main.h
int checkMouseDown[8];
int ShakerToogled;
class definition...
```

Listener.cpp

```
#include main.h

... update the Variables and create them...
```

Shaker.h

```
float intValue[16][10];
int SenderToogled;
```

Shaker.cpp

```
#include main.h

... update the Variables and create them...
```

main.c

```
#include Listener.h
#include shaker.h

do something... with the global arrays
```

Hope i could explain my Problem and u know some help.

Kindly Regards

PS: The Error is only on Mac not in Visual Studio in Windows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the Error, have changed the files to:

in the Shaker.h

```
extern int checkMouseDown[8];
```

in the Shaker.cpp

```
int checkMouseDown[8];
```

working now ;)